# Jquery animate problem

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate

This has code below has broken the jQuery:

```
$('.tabs li a').animate({
                height: '40'
              }, 1000, function() {
                // Animation complete.
              });

              $('#tabs-wrap').animate({
                marginTop: '-=147'
              }, 1000, function() {
                // Animation complete.
              });

              $('tabs li a').hover(function(){
                  $('tabs li a').animate({
                    height: '100'}, 1000, function(){
                          $('#tabs-wrap').animate({
                                marginTop: '+=147'
                            }, 1000, function(){

                      });
                  });
                }, function(){
                  $('tabs li a').animate({
                    height: '40'}, 1000, function(){
                          $('#tabs-wrap').animate({
                                marginTop: '-=147'
                            }, 1000, function(){

                      });
                  });  
              });
```

I know it looks a mess, sorry!

Can anyone spot whats going wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with what? is there a JS error? Unexpected results? Can you provide the HTML code or a JSFiddle with the code at hand?

Comment: No other jQuery on the page is now working which leads me to think i'm missing a comma or semicolon somewhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('tabs li a')` lacks a `'.'` to mark tabs as a class. That's one error - might be more.

Do us/yourself a favor and format the code properly before posting next time.

Comment: Additionally in your hover, it's not necessary to call the selector again.  ie within the callback in "hover" you can use "this" to point to the original selector.  (I believe the code I posted in your other question did this.)  As jsFiddle would be helpful to find what the exact problem is.)